# Noob trying Ubuntu 16.04 - Compiz error after logging in

Tags: nvidia, compiz, 16.04

After I try to login I see a background image and nothing else. If I right click a context menu briefly appears with options like 'new folder' etc.

Sometimes a dialogue box pops up briefly saying something about a compiz error.

Can anyone help me fix this? I really want to try Ubuntu but I have no idea what I'm doing.

GPU is an Nvidia 960.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known (and fixed) bug in 16.04, it will it fixed in 16.04.1.  But you can fix it now, don't worry :)

I did this:

boot with nomodeset (press E after grub is booted and add nomodeset after: quiet splash and press F10 (if I remember correctly) now change to a terminal with CTRL + ALT + F2 or something.

```
wget http://koti.kapsi.fi/~tjaalton/skl/build2/libllvm3.8_3.8-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libllvm3.8_3.8-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo reboot.
```

Tested on my own system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, good to hear it will be fixed in the next update.